# How to create an issue on Github using Postman with Github's API?

Tags: github, postman, github-api

I was trying to create an issue on GitHub using GitHub's API with Postman.

It does not work even after I provide the personal token generated on my site.

Does someone know what goes wrong?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it without the `/` on the end of the URL?

Comment: If the below answered your question please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

[As documented](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/opa/issues/972), a trailing slash in your URL

```
https://api.github.com/repos/hanc3/testapi/issues/
```

would result in an error.

Expect it would be a `405 (Method Not Allowed)`, when adding a slash at the endpoint causes the API to reject

In your case, it is a `404`, which means you did not properly authenticate when calling that API

Double-check your [postman Authorization tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40618418/6309): it should include a Authorization: token

And [headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53002640/6309):

```
Content-Type : application/json 
Authorization : token
```

See "[Rest API v3, Other Authentication Methods](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#via-oauth-and-personal-access-tokens)"